# Error: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create new columns with values derived from subtracting one existing column with another, but I get the error "Columns must be same length as key":

```
newcol = ['newcol1','newcol2','newcol3']
var_a = ['var_a1','var_a2','var_a3']
var_b = ['var_b1','var_b2','var_b3']
for new, a, b in zip(newcol, var_a, var_b):
    df[new] = df[a] - df[b]
```

However, if I try do this in the un-python way, I have no issues at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
newcol = ['newcol1','newcol2','newcol3']
var_a = ['var_a1','var_a2','var_a3']
var_b = ['var_b1','var_b2','var_b3']
for i in range(len(newcol)):
    df[newcol[i]] = df[var_a[i]] - df[var_b[i]]
```

Comment: Could you give a sample dataframe value?

Comment: Did the first code do something wrong, such as `df[newcol] = df[var_a] - df[var_b]` instead of `df[new] = df[a] - df[b]`?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does arithmetic operation based on row index and column header. In contract, the operation between NumPy array and DataFrame is elementwise since the NumPy array has no Panda-style row index and column header.

You can use `.values` to get the NumPy array from Pandas DataFrame

```py
df[newcol] = df[var_a] - df[var_b].values
```